# how to insert the image in mongodb using node.js gridfs

Tags: mongodb, express, nodes, gridfs

I am beginner in node.js. Can anyone tell how to store the image in mongodb using 
gridfs in nodejs program.How can I access the gridfs in nodejs can anyone upload the program

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Read this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would highly recommend not storing images directly in the DB. Instead, store references to images stored on your file system or a Cloud FS (like AWS S3/Glacier). This will keep your DB faster because images can eat up space.

Comment: that's what gridfs is for

Comment: thanks alex...but gridFS stores a files chunks still in the DB, not a reference to a file. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/
**Instead of storing a file in a single document, GridFS divides the file into parts, or chunks [1], and stores each chunk as a separate document.** So, a large file will still need to create multiple references to a DB, which is higher DB IO and less performance than native FS.

Comment: it's optimised for exactly this use case! See 'when to use' - In MongoDB, use GridFS for storing files larger than 16 MB.

Comment: You neglected the point **If your filesystem limits the number of files in a directory, you can use GridFS to store as many files as needed.** So, if you are not limited by your FS, its still faster to use that

Comment: you neglected the OP request - "how to store the image in mongodb using gridfs" - he didn't ask which was faster. Your question does not address the OP question!

Comment: Please provide some documentation you've read on the subject, what code you already have that you've already tried and what errors you encounter with it.  Otherwise, I'm with Alex.  The Stack Exchange community is here to provide certain assistance, advice and expertise, not labor.